# On a Famous Quote of Ven. Fulton Sheen Pertaining to the Laity

Tags: catholicism, reference-request, saint, laity

I have been trying to find the original source and transcript containing the following famous quote of Ven. Fulton J. Sheen on the laity:

> Who’s going to save our Church? It’s not our bishops, it’s not our priests and it is not the religious. It is up to you, the people. You have the minds, the eyes and the ears to save the Church. Your mission is to see that the priests act like priests, your bishops act like bishops, and the religious act like religious.

I have read that it said it at the Supreme Convention of the Knights of Columbus in June of 1972, but I would like to locate, if possible, an audio recording or a transcript of the speech. Would anyone know where I can find such?

If he uttered this quote earlier than this, it would be very helpful to know this.